# Which options is correct? "I studied at / I was educated at / I was up at / I went school"

Tags: word-usage

Which is preferred when I want to say about a university studies?

> I studied at / I was educated at / I was up at / I went school

Comment: The usage ***to be up** [at university]* is a very dated British usage. Avoid it. And don't confuse ***school*** (education up to 16 or 18) with ***university*** ("**higher** education"). Finally, I don't think many people would say they were ***educated*** at university - where you were educated is like where you were ***brought up*** (these are things you do or have done to you ***before** becoming an "adult" who might marry, join the army, vote, etc.*).

Comment: _Educated at_ usually refers to your secondary school. We say _I went **to** school_, but that, at least in British English, also refers to secondary (or primary) education. You can say "I studied [subject] at X University" or "I have a degree in [subject] from X University. _Up at_ is an old-fashioned expression which I associate with Oxford and Cambridge students a century or more ago.

Comment: What location are we talking about? "School" has different meanings in UK vs USA

Comment: "I was up at" is not how it would be said in BrE anyway, rather: "I went up to <college-name>"